# How to persistently check for messages incoming to my telegram bot using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am experimenting with telegram bots and python. My question is how can I make my python program persistently check for messages which are sent to my telegram bot?

for example:

```
while checkForIncomingMessages:
    print(latestMessage)
    if latestMessage == "ifconfig":
       # execute ifconfig command on laptop
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are example bots on the github page of the telegrambot.

[echobot2](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/echobot2.py)